# Store and retrieve user data in IOS keychain

Tags: keychain

I am developing an application where i need to store and retrieve user data like (user name, password, url, domain name etc) using keychain. But i found there predefine keys available like, (kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrDescription, kSecAttrComment, kSecValueData etc). Earlier i was using Plist to store thise information.

So can anyone help me, how to use keychain for storage.

I have gone through apple sample project that is only using for login and password.

Can i use dictionary (contain all user data) to setobject in keychain and get dictionary from it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've created a very simple wrapper around the Keychain. It works very similar to NSDictionary with setValue and objectForKey methods.

https://github.com/reidmain/FDKeychain